# Understanding example code for processbuilder in Java

Tags: java, processbuilder

I have some example code where a process builder is used and given two commands to execute, but I can't fully understand what each line of code is doing.

Also the commands don't seem to be actually executing.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> commands = new ArrayList(); // commands in a processbuilder is an Arraylist of of strings
    commands.add("myfile.pdf"); // supposed to open the file?
    commands.add("bash\", \"-c\", \"ls"); // supposed to use ls command in terminal
    execute(commands); // should execute the two commands above
    System.out.println("executed commands"); // only thing that actually happens
}

public static void execute(ArrayList<String> command) {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command); // a new builder which takes a command passed into the method
        Map<String, String> environ = builder.environment(); // ???
        Process p = builder.start(); // p is never used?
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I get no errors or warnings.

Tried reading the API on the processbuilder but I didn't really understand it

Answer (score 1):

`ProcessBuilder` helps to start external processes.

First, the command line parts (executable, parameters) are taken as a list of `String`, which is very comfortable. ("`command`" is rather misleading here, since it consists of executable and parameters).

Second, you can edit the environment of the new process (environment variables like "`$HOME`", "`$PATH`", etc.).

Your `p` can be used, for example to check, if the process has finished yet or to retrieve the input/output of the new process. Since you only start the process (fire-and-forget), you don't need it here.

You may also use `Runtime.exec(...)` to start an external process, which is the historical way to do so, but I think it's more comfortable to use `ProcessBuilder`.